# Order of execution of recursive function

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I recently tried this problem:

> There are `N` wines in a row. Each year you sell either the leftmost or the rightmost wine. The `i`-th wine has initial price `arr[i]` and price `y*arr[i]` in the `y`-th year. What is the maximum possible total profit?

I was able to solve the problem correctly using recursion, but I cannot understand the order of execution of the program.

The code is:

```
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int func(int arr[],int n,int l, int r, int y){
    if(y>n)
      return 0;
    if(l>n-1)
      return 0;
    if(r<0)
      return 0;

    cout<<"l is: "<<l<<" and r is: "<<r<<endl;

    int sum=max(arr[l]*y+func(arr,n,l+1,r,y+1), arr[r]*y+func(arr,n,l,r-1,y+1));

    return sum;
  }  


  int main()
  {
    int n=0;

    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
      cin>>arr[i];
    }

    cout<<func(arr,n,0,n-1,1);

    return 0;
  }
```

For input `n= 5` & `values= 2,4,6,2,5`

Output is:

```
l is: 0 and r is: 4
l is: 0 and r is: 3
l is: 0 and r is: 2
l is: 0 and r is: 1
l is: 0 and r is: 0
l is: 1 and r is: 1
l is: 1 and r is: 2
l is: 1 and r is: 1
l is: 2 and r is: 2
l is: 1 and r is: 3
l is: 1 and r is: 2
l is: 1 and r is: 1
l is: 2 and r is: 2
l is: 2 and r is: 3
l is: 2 and r is: 2
l is: 3 and r is: 3
l is: 1 and r is: 4
l is: 1 and r is: 3
l is: 1 and r is: 2
l is: 1 and r is: 1
l is: 2 and r is: 2
l is: 2 and r is: 3
l is: 2 and r is: 2
l is: 3 and r is: 3
l is: 2 and r is: 4
l is: 2 and r is: 3
l is: 2 and r is: 2
l is: 3 and r is: 3
l is: 3 and r is: 4
l is: 3 and r is: 3
l is: 4 and r is: 4
64
```

Due to multiple parameters, I am not able to visualize what the recursion is doing. Please explain how the recursion begins execution, and also how to visualize recursion where more parameters are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all parameter evaluation order in C++ is not defined. See : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order  Arguments of max is in your case evaulated from right to left.

First you are calling the function with initial parameters:

```
l = 0 , r = n-1, y = 1
```

When statement 
`int sum=max(arr[l]*y+func(arr,n,l+1,r,y+1), arr[r]*y+func(arr,n,l,r-1,y+1));`
 
is reached, right side is evaluated and the function is called for `func(arr,n,0,r-1,y+1)` . because the rightmost element is picked up in year y and now the rightmost element is now residing at index `r-1`. when you call function in year `y+1` again the right most function is called for `r-2` and `y+2` and `r-3` and `y+3` and so on until you hit a base case in recursion.

The function is hitting base case for the first time when r equals -1.

```
l is: 0 and r is: 0
```

is printed when r is 0. This means that you did :

```
int sum=max(arr[0]*y+func(arr,n,0+1,0,y+1), arr[0]*y+func(arr,n,0,-1,y+1));
```

then right side is called for

`func(arr,n,0,-1,y+n-1)` . note that l is still zero because always right side of recursion has been called. then `if(r<0)` case returns the function. then left side of previous step is evaluated. Since there is again recursion which goes until `l>n-1` by incrementing l each step.

This is called depth first search.

Comment: Well I thought that the execution should start from the left. So is it that it will always start from right in case we have more parameters or as you said it is undefined.

Comment: No if the first call executes the right side then this is feature of your compiler. Then first right sides are called until it reaches to base case. Then In the lowest level a right side function returned, left sides are called until hitting base case.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply